# WP_User_Query - searching multiple fields

Tags: users, wp-user-query

I have a search engine where I can search for users on the front end. Profiles have mulitple custom fields. I'm just searching first and last name in this example. The problem is I can search for a last or first name, but not both combined...

```
 $my_users = new WP_User_Query( 
      array( 
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'key' => 'first_name',
                    'value' => $search,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ), 
                array(
                    'key' => 'last_name',
                    'value' => $search,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ), 
            )
      ));
```